# Calculating in input

Tags: verilog

I want to count the number of 1's in an 8-bit input and output how many ones are in it. The way I am finding this is very crude and redundant. I want to know if there is any easy and good way of finding them. My code looks like:

```
module my_8to4bit(in,out);

input [7:0]in;
output [3:0]out;


assign out=(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 4 || input == 8 || input == 16 || input == 32 || input == 64 || input == 128)?1:
(input == 3 || input == 5 || input == 6 || input == 9 || input == 10 || input == 12 || input == 24 || input == 128)?2:0;
```

... same goes upto all 1's in 8bit input.

Is there an easy way of finding them?

Comment: ...and it seems you made an error, too: `input == 128) ? 2:0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
always @* begin
  out = 0;
  for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1) begin
    out = out + in[i];
  end
end
```

Should just synthesize to 8 adders, one for each bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to synthesize the code, and your simulator supports SystemVerilog syntax, you can use the `$countones` system function.  Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2009, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up answers in [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).  If speed is important and space is not an issue, you might consider a 256-byte lookup table.  Otherwise, probably use [Brian Kernighan's way](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan) (and measure whether it is actually slower than the lookup table; it may be faster than the lookup table if memory is slow and the CPU is fast).

Comment: This is for HDL, not CPU programming language, so I'm not sure if most of those are appropriate.